# InitialLOBFetchSize = -1 crashes app pool

Tags: oracle

We have a few Oracle customers and we noticed a good performance increase by setting InitialLOBFetchsize to -1.  It works really well on one customers database but we have another one where it is causing the app pool to crash.  If I take out that line and leave it to default, the app pool does not crash.  We are running both databases in the same environment, so I am wondering what could cause the one database to crash whereas the other one is fine with this setting?

Is there some type of parameter that could be causing the issue within the bad customers database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. Check your Oracle.DataAccess.dll version. Mine was 4.112.2.0 and then I upgraded it to 4.112.3.0 and that fixed the issue.